# There is an incomprehensible space between my post columns, how to fix it?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am building a blog page for myself using php, I managed to get data from mysql and show the posts on the page, but when the posts have shown, there are some spaces which I can't understand why do they appear.

I've tried to put every three div, which has col-md-4 class, in a different row but didn't work. It works as I want when I make the class of the container "container-fluid" but I don't want to use it that way.

```
<div id="colorlib-container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--
        *design the sidebar so it shows the last three posts by using LIMIT.
        -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="side">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Enter any key to search...">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="icon-search3"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                        <h2 class="sidebar-heading">Categories</h2>
                        <p>
                            <ul class="category">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blog.php?category=G%C3%BCnl%C3%BCk+Hayat#colorlib-container">
                                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Günlük Hayat
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blog.php?category=Genel#colorlib-container">
                                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Genel
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                        <h2 class="sidebar-heading">Categories</h2>
                        <p>
                            <ul class="category">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blog.php?category=G%C3%BCnl%C3%BCk+Hayat#colorlib-container">
                                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Günlük Hayat
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blog.php?category=Genel#colorlib-container">
                                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Genel
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                        <h2 class="sidebar-heading">Categories</h2>
                        <p>
                            <ul class="category">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blog.php?category=G%C3%BCnl%C3%BCk+Hayat#colorlib-container">
                                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Günlük Hayat
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blog.php?category=Genel#colorlib-container">
                                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Genel
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                        <h2 class="sidebar-heading">Son Gönderiler</h2>
                        <div class="f-blog">
                            <a href="post.php?id=16" class="blog-img" style="background-image: url(images/blog-3.jpg);"></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="blog.html">post başlığı</a>
                                </h3>
                                <p class="admin">
                                    <span>2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f-blog">
                            <a href="post.php?id=15" class="blog-img" style="background-image: url(images/blog-3.jpg);"></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="blog.html">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                                </h3>
                                <p class="admin">
                                    <span>2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f-blog">
                            <a href="post.php?id=14" class="blog-img" style="background-image: url(images/blog-3.jpg);"></a>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="blog.html">post başlığı</a>
                                </h3>
                                <p class="admin">
                                    <span>2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="blog-entry">
                    <div class="blog-img">
                        <a href="post.php?id=9">
                            <img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="html5 bootstrap template">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="desc">
                            <p class="meta">
                                <span class="cat">
                                    <a href="#">Günlük Hayat</a>
                                </span>
                                <span class="date">2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                                <span class="pos">By 
                                    <a href="#">cgrdmz</a>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                            <h2>
                                <a href="post.php?id=9">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                            </h2>
                            <p>merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. Bu velet bilgisayar oyunları oynamayı küçük yaşlarından beri çok seviyor.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="blog-entry">
                        <div class="blog-img">
                            <a href="post.php?id=11">
                                <img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="html5 bootstrap template">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <p class="meta">
                                    <span class="cat">
                                        <a href="#">Günlük Hayat</a>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="date">2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                                    <span class="pos">By 
                                        <a href="#">cgrdmz</a>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="post.php?id=11">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                                </h2>
                                <p>merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="blog-entry">
                            <div class="blog-img">
                                <a href="post.php?id=13">
                                    <img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="html5 bootstrap template">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <p class="meta">
                                        <span class="cat">
                                            <a href="#">Günlük Hayat</a>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="date">2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                                        <span class="pos">By 
                                            <a href="#">cgrdmz</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                    <h2>
                                        <a href="post.php?id=13">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                                    </h2>
                                    <p>merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="blog-entry">
                                <div class="blog-img">
                                    <a href="post.php?id=15">
                                        <img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="html5 bootstrap template">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="desc">
                                        <p class="meta">
                                            <span class="cat">
                                                <a href="#">Günlük Hayat</a>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="date">2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                                            <span class="pos">By 
                                                <a href="#">cgrdmz</a>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                        <h2>
                                            <a href="post.php?id=15">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                                        </h2>
                                        <p>merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYfQg.jpg

As shown in the image, I will have only 4 posts in a page, so I just want them to look decent.

edit: it works with minified bootstrap correctly but normal version still makes it weird.

Comment: I think there are missing closing tags in the code you posted, and there are a couple of `<a>` tags missing quotes in their `href` attributes (blog.php?category=Genel#colorlib-container). If you could fix that up, maybe post it in a fiddle or codepen, that would make it a lot easier to diagnose!

Comment: @Frish This is the first time I ask a question, so I couldn't be sure how exactly the code should be. I use php on the server side but as this question is about a frontend problem I opened the compiled source code in google chrome and copied the related part and put it into a online html beautifier, probably this caused the missing quotes. I am sure there are a lot of better ways to do it but that was what I could think of at the moment. Whatever, the missing quotes are added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the overall layout for your rows and columns were set out incorrectly. The solution I recommend is to have two nested rows. Your first row will contain two columns: the first column to hold the sidebar, and the seconds column to hold the posts. Within the posts column, there should be another row, with each column set to col-6, allowing for only 2 posts per row (given there is a max 12 columns), and what ever follows will wrap to the next line.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style></style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="colorlib-container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
          <!--
                *design the sidebar so it shows the last three posts by using LIMIT.
                -->
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="sidebar">
              <div class="side">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Enter any key to search...">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="icon-search3"></i>
                                </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="side">
                <h2 class="sidebar-heading">Categories</h2>
                <p>
                  <ul class="category">
                    <li>
                      <a href="blog.php?category=G%C3%BCnl%C3%BCk+Hayat#colorlib-container"><i class="icon-check"></i> Günlük Hayat</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="blog.php?category=Genel#colorlib-container">
                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Genel
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="side">
                <h2 class="sidebar-heading">Categories</h2>
                <p>
                  <ul class="category">
                    <li>
                      <a href="blog.php?category=G%C3%BCnl%C3%BCk+Hayat#colorlib-container">
                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Günlük Hayat
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="blog.php?category=Genel#colorlib-container">
                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Genel
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="side">
                <h2 class="sidebar-heading">Categories</h2>
                <p>
                  <ul class="category">
                    <li>
                      <a href="blog.php?category=G%C3%BCnl%C3%BCk+Hayat#colorlib-container">
                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Günlük Hayat
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="blog.php?category=Genel#colorlib-container">
                        <i class="icon-check"></i> Genel
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="side">
                <h2 class="sidebar-heading">Son Gönderiler</h2>
                <div class="f-blog">
                  <a href="post.php?id=16" class="blog-img" style="background-image: url(images/blog-3.jpg);"></a>
                  <div class="desc">
                    <h3>
                      <a href="blog.html">post başlığı</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="admin">
                      <span>2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-blog">
                  <a href="post.php?id=15" class="blog-img" style="background-image: url(images/blog-3.jpg);"></a>
                  <div class="desc">
                    <h3>
                      <a href="blog.html">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="admin">
                      <span>2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-blog">
                  <a href="post.php?id=14" class="blog-img" style="background-image: url(images/blog-3.jpg);"></a>
                  <div class="desc">
                    <h3>
                      <a href="blog.html">post başlığı</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="admin">
                      <span>2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="blog-entry">
              <div class="blog-img">
                <a href="post.php?id=9">
                  <img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="html5 bootstrap template">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="desc">
                <p class="meta">
                  <span class="cat"><a href="#">Günlük Hayat</a></span>
                  <span class="date">2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                  <span class="pos">By <a href="#">cgrdmz</a></span>
                </p>
                <h2>
                  <a href="post.php?id=9">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                </h2>
                <p>
                  merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. Bu velet bilgisayar oyunları oynamayı küçük yaşlarından beri çok seviyor.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="blog-entry">
              <div class="blog-img">
                <a href="post.php?id=11">
                  <img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="html5 bootstrap template">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="desc">
                <p class="meta">
                  <span class="cat"><a href="#">Günlük Hayat</a></span>
                  <span class="date">2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                  <span class="pos">By <a href="#">cgrdmz</a></span>
                </p>
                <h2>
                  <a href="post.php?id=11">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                </h2>
                <p>
                  merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="blog-entry">
              <div class="blog-img">
                <a href="post.php?id=13">
                  <img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="html5 bootstrap template">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="desc">
                <p class="meta">
                  <span class="cat"><a href="#">Günlük Hayat</a></span>
                  <span class="date">2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                  <span class="pos">By <a href="#">cgrdmz</a></span>
                </p>
                <h2>
                  <a href="post.php?id=13">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                </h2>
                <p>
                  merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="blog-entry">
              <div class="blog-img">
                <a href="post.php?id=15">
                  <img src="images/blog-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="html5 bootstrap template">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="desc">
                <p class="meta">
                  <span class="cat"><a href="#">Günlük Hayat</a></span>
                  <span class="date">2019-05-10 18:28:10</span>
                  <span class="pos">By <a href="#">cgrdmz</a></span>
                </p>
                <h2>
                  <a href="post.php?id=15">Tuğrul'un Roblox Sevdası</a>
                </h2>
                <p>
                  merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul. merhaba! benim bbir kardeşim var, ismi tuğrul.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried the nested rows exactly the same way as you did but still same result, also i noticed my posts are not ordered left to right, maybe this points something? [here is a picture about it and it shows the structure of my elements.](https://imgur.com/j8NaeMX)

Comment: I changed my bootstrap.css file with bootstrap minified version and it worked. Can you try normal bootstrap and see if you face the same problem.

Comment: That's interesting. I wouldn't think a minified version would make any difference. It might have something to do with the version of Bootstrap you were using. I was using version 4.1.3. What version were you using before you tried the minified one?

Comment: It works with version 3.3.7 when i use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">` but instead if i download the same version  and add this to header  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">` some classes doesn't work right. Also in Eclipse Built-in web application it works fine, too.

Comment: So the CDN works, but if you download the same file to access it directly, it doesn't work. Doesn't make sense. Perhaps there's a caching issue when you access the file directly. If the browser thinks it has the file already, it's not going to load it again.Try clearing your cache. You can add a version number as a parameter to your file name, just to test: href="css/bootstrap.min.css?v=1.2" . Since it hasn't loaded it before with the version parameter, it will load it again. If it's not a caching issue, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, i added the version like you did and it worked out. I guess it is something with chrome.